# Can a neighbor legally attach something to the top rail of an existing common fence in Alberta?

Tags: property, easement, alberta, common-property

My neighbor built a shed on their side of our common fence. They used the top rail to rest the end boards and also the roof supports on that end. I want to replace the boards along that entire side and I cannot as they have refused to remove that part of their structure.

What are my rights???